# Garbage collection in Rebol & Red

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, rebol, red

Do [Rebol](http://www.rebol.com) and [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/) have automatic or manual methods for garbage collection or memory management to avoid system crashes?

If so, what are the methods that can be called manually to clear up memory problems?

Comment: *"Rebol ... seem to be new programming languages"* => depends on your standards for "new".  Rebol 1.0 was [released in 1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebol), 20 years ago at time of writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebol has garbage collection [see recycle](http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wrecycle.html) ,

Red will get it, [see trello](https://trello.com/b/FlQ6pzdB/red-tasks-overview)

Comment: That is great news.  Please see my compile question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210235/compile-rebol-code-to-executable

Comment: Red already has a simple garbage collector: https://www.red-lang.org/2018/12/064-simple-gc-and-pure-red-gui-console.html